# php: queue / dont delay the user

Tags: php, queue

I have a piece of code that takes a while to run and is low priority. I was wondering if in PHP I can do something like

```
public function put () {

  $comment = array('title' => 'my title', 'description' => 'my description');

  sendtoQueue($this->internalCall('controller' => 'Comment', 'data' => $comment);

  $object = $this->get('id' => $this->id);
  return $object;
}
```

Where the function inside sendToQueue wouldnt delay the $object being fetching and returned and would be run in the BG.

Possible? I know I can throw it to python but ideally I'd like it to be run within the current scope.

Comment: Why don't you just execute the script from AJAX?

Comment: This is an API project, the PUT request is doing many things but the response is being slowed down by some of them that are less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to run in the current scope than you could fork ([pcntl_fork()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)) a process and let the child handle this whilst the parent carries on

Otherwise just run a script periodically that empties a queue of tasks.

Comment: and, be prepared to struggle with opened connection issues. Also, as far as I know, the child processes die when the parent process dies. Our web process is going to die at the end of http request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to start a new php process that runs the script in the background and make sendToQueue return.

You could also use a solution like [beanstalkD](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/). Where sendtoQueue pushes data to Beanstalk and have workers empty your queue in the background

Comment: Exec doesn't keep the scope of the current user or action, which is why I wanted to avoid doing it, because I have to create a new script to redo whats already coded.

BeanstalkD looks interesting, I feel this is probably the only way to go unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could easily do with [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) library. First, you can choose from a variety of transports, such as AMQP, STOMP, Redis, Amazon SQS, Filesystem and so on.

Secondly, That's super easy to use. Let's start from installation:

You have to install the `enqueue/simple-client` library and [one of the transports](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/tree/master/docs/transport). Assuming you choose the filesystem one, install `enqueue/fs` library. To summarize:

```
composer require enqueue/simple-client enqueue/fs
```

Now let's see how you can send messages from your POST script:

```
<?php
// producer.php

use Enqueue\SimpleClient\SimpleClient;

include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new SimpleClient('file://'); // the queue will store messages in tmp folder

$client->sendEvent('a_topic', 'aMessageData');
```

The consumption script:

```
<?php
// consumer.php

use Enqueue\SimpleClient\SimpleClient;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrProcessor;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrMessage;

include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new SimpleClient('file://');

$client->bind('a_topic', 'a_processor_name', function(PsrMessage $psrMessage) {
   // processing logic here

   return PsrProcessor::ACK;
});

// this call is optional but it worth to mention it.
// it configures a broker, for example it can create queues and excanges on RabbitMQ side. 
$client->setupBroker();

$client->consume();
```

Run as many `consumer.php` processes as you by using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or other process managers, on local computer you can run it without any extra libs or packages.

That's a basic example and enqueue has a lot of other features that might come in handy. If you are interested, check the [enqueue documentation](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/index.md) out.